# Подсчёт цены в корзине

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы, корзина

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться с массивами и sql запросом...
В чем заключается вопрос:
Есть сайт, на нём есть корзина для индексации выбранных продуктов пользователем,
когда пользователь выбирает что хочет купить, товар записывается в сессию в виде

```
$_SESSION['goods'][$goods]=array($goods, $count);
```

ГДЕ $goods - ID товара, а $count - количество товара

Мне же нужно потом вытащить id в запрос SQL и узнать цену товара, что бы потом всё это посчитать вместе и дать покупателю полную цену всех выбранных товаров.. Сколько не пробовал не могу никак сообразить как, помогите пожалуйста с вопросом

Удаление и занесение в корзину товаров происходит так

```
if(isset($_SESSION['goods'])){
foreach($_SESSION['goods'] as $pr){ 
if($goods == $pr[0]){
$count = $oper=='plus'?($pr[1]+1):($pr[1]-1); 
if ($count<1){unset($_SESSION['goods'][$goods]);
unset($pr[0]); unset($goods);
$new_arr = array_values($old_arr);
}}}};
$_SESSION['goods'][$goods]=array($goods, $count);
```

Comment: видимо пробежать по сессии, найти id всех товаров и сделать запрос вроде `select id, price from tab where id in(1,5,56,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем же записывать 2 раза id товара, проще сохраняйте id как ключ, а значение будет количество:

```
$_SESSION['goods'][$goods] = $count;
```

И потом к примеру если вы циклом проходитесь по товарам делаете вот так и всё:

```
foreach($_SESSION['goods'] as $id => $count) {
    //SQL запрос, в который подставляете $id
}
```

Можно сразу все товары взять к примеру, тогда собираете ключи массива и вставляете в SQL запрос:

```
$ids = array_keys($_SESSION['goods']);
```

Comment: Плохой совет! На каждый товар по 1 запросу это ужас.

Comment: @Visman добавил вариант для выборки сразу всех id

Comment: Не могу всё понять как вытащить цены из базы данных по id в массиве

Comment: @Harron смотря как вы с базой работаете и какая структура базы, это известно только вам